# Django CMS place holder is not displaying

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I've tried to render a placeholder inside a custom cms plugin. From some reason I can see place holder tag is created in the DOM, but when I switch to edit mode, I don't see the placeholder anywhere. I can't create any plugins in that placeholder.

Here is the code:

models.py

```
class TabItem(CMSPlugin):
    tab_name = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    place_holder = PlaceholderField("place_holder_name")
```

cms_plugins.py

```
class TabItemPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    module = _("c2ms_module_information_tab")
    model = TabItem
    name = _("Tab Item")
    render_template = "c2ms_module_information_tab/tab.html"
    allow_children = True

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context.update({
            'instance': instance,
            'placeholder': placeholder,
        })
        return context
```

Template:

```
{% load cms_tags staticfiles sekizai_tags placeholder_tags %}
<a href="#">{{ instance.tab_name|safe }}</a>
<div class="expanded">
    {% render_placeholder instance.place_holder "640" %}
</div>
```

Comment: I've never tried to render a placeholder myself in a plugin, what's the idea behind this? I'm not in a position to test this at the moment. I'd be tempted to raise an issue on the project's github. https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues

Comment: @marksweb This is what I've looking at when trying to render the placeholder https://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/develop/how_to/placeholders.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue here is that you're trying to create a placeholder as a `CMSPlugin`. Plugins sit within a placeholder but I've never seen a plugin contain a placeholder.

What you're then trying to do I assume is to have a placeholder on a base template which is set to display your `TabItem` plugin which in turn is intended to render another placeholder.

I've not written this up, but I believe what you should be doing is something like this;

models.py;

```
from django.db import models

from cms.models import CMSPlugin
from cms.models.fields import PlaceholderField


class TabItem(models.Model):
    tab_name = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    placeholder = PlaceholderField("place_holder_name")


class TabPlugin(CMSPlugin):
    tab_name = models.CharField(max_length=8)
```

admin.py;

```
from django.contrib import admin

from cms.admin.placeholderadmin import PlaceholderAdmin

from .models import TabItem


class TabItemAdmin(PlaceholderAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(TabItem, TabItemAdmin)
```

From that you can add your custom placeholder to a template which in turn renders your plugin. At least that is my understanding from the docs - [Placeholders outside the CMS](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/3.0/extending_cms/placeholders.html)